# Do ads that pop up in a new tab hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, google, advertising

Today a lot ad companies offer propeller ads instead of popup ads.  I read how popup ads can hurt Google rankings.   Those articles say that Google hates ads that pop up in new window.

However, these propeller ads are opened in new tab.

Would a propeller ad opened in new tab also hurt SEO like an ad that pops up in a new window?

Comment: Google tries to find what "users like best", It's their core business to find websites which a user might like, and make sure users are shown those sites when they want. Any advertisement that "requires interaction to go away" is greatly disliked by users. So obviously it will hurt it, if Google can detect these things, I'm not sure if Google can or not but if Google cannot they will be able in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul mentioned - keep your website tidy and make sure you offer real value and benefit to your user. So hearing pop-ups I instantly flinch. However, if it is a "modal" (kind of a pop up that appears above the page - like a privacy policy/cookie policy reminder) then it is fine.

If it's a modal it won't hurt your SEO, we ran a number of promotional "Modal boxes" - (not pop-ups per se) and it didn't make a difference. Then again, the site is a popular brand and has more than a million visitors a day. So I wasn't expecting to fluctuate.

If you want to be fancy - don't show the modal to SE Crawlers. Here's [one way](https://www.onely.com/blog/detect-verify-crawlers/) of achieving this. Mind you I haven't read the article, so there might be better ones out there. But detecting bots isn't necessarily rocket science - especially if you are on a Web Application Framework like Rails or Django. CMS wise I am not necessarily the go-to guy.

Comment: For what it's worth, the linked page had a modal popup and I instinctively backed out of that page. Had I reached that page from Google search which would have tracked the page time, this could hurt SEO as I would have clicked another result instead.